# CN1 - unable to use localization after activating css

Tags: localization, codenameone

Recently I switched over from the legacy css integration to using the current method of css support via the CN1 Preferences dialog. Ever since then, I've had repeated problems accessing strings from the localization resource file.

A few important points:

- I have two theme files, but even importing the strings as a csv file into the theme generated by css doesn't work
- I've tried all possible combinations of theme initialization with the two theme files, including initializing just one of them, with no consistent success (occasionally it works, but then if I modify the css and the theme file gets regenerated it stops working again)
- I created a brand new project and copied my code into it, imported the string files, and it worked - until I turned on css support.  Then I was back to square one
- When it fails to work, the method `UIManager.getL10NResourceNames()` returns an empty array

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much poking around, I found the solution. It turns out my situation was the result of a few non-standard things I did.  First of all, I had a `theme.res` file which I renamed using IntelliJ's `Refactor >> Rename` function, which renamed the hardcoded css theme name in the `build.xml` file to my new name.  I needed to manually revert that string in order to prevent the css compile task from overwriting my theme file.  The second thing I noticed is that sometimes (I'm not clear on what caused this) the theme file was not being refreshed in the `/out` directory when running the app locally.  This would manifest itself, for instance, when I would add an image in the theme file, but when running the code it wouldn't be able to find it in the `Resources` hashtable.  Every time this happens, I now know to just delete the contents of `/out`, thereby forcing the IDE to rebuild/recopy the theme file (I could probably just copy it manually to the `/out` directory, but I think deleting it is safest).

Answer (score 0):

CSS controls the file and as a result you can no longer change the theme.res file by other means. You need to keep a separate localization.res file and load that strictly for the localization functionality of your application. You can use `Resources.open("/localization.res")` to load an arbitrary resource file.

Comment: I'm able to load the theme file using `Resources.open()`, but still the localization table is empty

Comment: This needs to be a separate resource file which is unrelated to the one generated by CSS